# Docker is unable to delete a file when building images

Tags: docker

My DockerFile contains the following instruction:

```
rm -f plugins.7z
```

This command worked as expected in earlier versions of docker but fails with version 1.13. I see the error:

```
cannot access plugins.7z: No such file or directory
```

If I bring up a container with the base image and execute the command manually, I see the same error.

Trying to list the folder contents displays:

```
# ls -lrt
  ls: cannot access plugins.7z: No such file or directory
  total 12
  ???????????   ? ?          ?             ?            ? plugins.7z
```

This is not listed as a known issue in [Docker Issues](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues). How do I debug the issue further?

Edit:

1. For reasons of IP, I cannot post the full Dockerfile here. Also, it may not be necessary. As I mentioned, I am able to simulate the issue even by manually running the container and trying to execute the command
2. The file exists before I attempt to delete it
3. I was wrong about there not being a similar bug in the issues list. Here is [one](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/783)
4. The issue may not be to do with that file. Deleting other files/folders in the folder also makes them appear with ??? permissions
5. The user performing the operation is root

Comment: can you post your full Dockerfile ?

Comment: Where is the plugins file? which directory? maybe you are trying to delete it from the wrong path?

Comment: I ran into this issue with Docker 1.12.6 -- the issue is with the filesystem supporting d_type, as fully explained in the answers+comments below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason removing directories fails is that the backing (`xfs`) filesystem was not formatted with d_type support ("ftype=1"); you can find a discussion on github; https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27358.

To verify if `d_type` support is available on your system, check the output of `docker info`;

```
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: false
Logging Driver: json-file
```

This requirement is also described in the [release notes for RHEL/CentOS](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.2_Release_Notes/technology-preview-file_systems.html)

> Note that XFS file systems must be created with the `-n ftype=1` option enabled for use as an overlay. With the rootfs and any file systems created during system installation, set the `--mkfsoptions=-n ftype=1` parameters in the Anaconda kickstart. When creating a new file system after the installation, run the `# mkfs -t xfs -n ftype=1 /PATH/TO/DEVICE` command. To determine whether an existing file system is eligible for use as an overlay, run the `# xfs_info /PATH/TO/DEVICE | grep ftype` command to see if the `ftype=1` option is enabled.

To resolve the issue, either;

- re-format the device with `ftype=1`
- use a different storage driver. Note that the default device mapper configuration (which uses loopback devices) is not recommended for production use, so requires manual configuration.

For backward-compatibility (older versions of docker allowed running overlay on systems without `d_type`), docker 1.13 will only log a *warning* in the daemon logs (https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/27433), but will no longer be supported in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get past the issue.

The [change log](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for 1.13 says

```
"IMPORTANT: On Linux distributions where devicemapper was the default
storage driver, the overlay2, or overlay is now used by default 
(if the kernel supports it)."
```

So I tried putting back devicemapper and it is now working as expected.

Comment: can you share some more details as how ?

Comment: @VatsalPrakash what I tried was only a stop-gap measure. Please see the accepted answer. The right solution is to install docker on a disk with a different file system.

Comment: Oh.. Thanxx.. :)