# Docker is unable to delete a directory when building images

Tags: docker

The issue is similar to [Docker is unable to delete a file when building images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527413/docker-is-unable-to-delete-a-file-when-building-images)

However, the route cause isn't the same, because `d_type` is enabled in my case.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:latest

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /usr/share/doc
```

When trying to build the image

```
docker build -t arm64v8-ubuntu-test .
```

I get the following error

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/2 : FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:latest
 ---> 499b06aa549b
Step 2/2 : RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /usr/share/doc
 ---> Running in 5ff328ef5a57
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/sed': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libpam-modules': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/util-linux': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mawk': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/gnupg': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/apt': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libreadline6': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/passwd': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mount': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/procps': Directory not empty
The command '/bin/sh -c export DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /usr/share/doc' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My docker info is

```
$ docker info
Containers: 7
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 6
Images: 95
Server Version: 17.10.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: mjm8vu1ixmw1ls25dk7gomiva
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: lnspgxtrca8d4lm3kfv7zbz77
 Managers: 3
 Nodes: 3
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.0.4.71
 Manager Addresses:
  10.0.4.71:2377
  10.0.4.72:2377
  10.0.4.73:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 0351df1c5a66838d0c392b4ac4cf9450de844e2d
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.14.79-27-ARCH
Operating System: Arch Linux ARM
OSType: linux
Architecture: aarch64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 1.928GiB
Name: alarm-docker-manager-host
ID: Y5ZZ:5G3O:KIE2:MSQX:7MBB:XWOZ:CYLL:2SSY:GTMB:YCBG:4TTT:EJVN
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Manually running the container and trying to execute the command has the same result, for example

```
$ docker run --rm -it arm64v8/ubuntu:latest bash
root@87a3ea8fecdd:~# rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /usr/share/doc
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/sed': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libpam-modules': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/util-linux': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mawk': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/gnupg': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/apt': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libreadline6': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/passwd': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mount': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/procps': Directory not empty
```

Also, the permissions seem fine, the directory is there, and is not being used by another process

```
root@87a3ea8fecdd:/# ls -lah /
total 68K
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4.0K Oct 19 06:43 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4.0K Oct 19 06:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Oct 19 06:43 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr 12  2016 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  360 Oct 19 06:44 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4.0K Oct 19 06:43 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr 12  2016 home
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct  6 01:43 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct  6 01:43 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct  6 01:43 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 143 root root    0 Oct 19 06:43 proc
drwx------   2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 root
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4.0K Oct  6 01:44 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct  6 01:43 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  12 root root    0 Oct 19 06:43 sys
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root 4.0K Oct  6 01:44 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 var

root@87a3ea8fecdd:/# ls -lah /var/lib/apt
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 ..
-rw-r--r--  5 root root    0 Oct  6 01:44 extended_states
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 keyrings
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 11 14:01 lists
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 mirrors
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Apr 14  2016 periodic

root@87a3ea8fecdd:/# ls -lah /usr/share
total 160K
drwxr-xr-x 40 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 adduser
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 apport
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 base-files
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 base-passwd
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 bash-completion
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 bug
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 common-licenses
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 dbus-1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 debconf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 debianutils
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Apr 12  2016 dict
drwxr-xr-x 94 root root 4.0K Oct 19 05:39 doc
...

root@df3ef4561fc3:/# lsof /usr/share/doc
root@df3ef4561fc3:/# rm -rf /usr/share/doc
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/sed': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libpam-modules': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/util-linux': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mawk': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/gnupg': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/apt': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libreadline6': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/passwd': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mount': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/procps': Directory not empty
```

Rmdir doesn't work either

```
root@df3ef4561fc3:/# rmdir /usr/share/doc
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/doc': Directory not empty
root@df3ef4561fc3:/# lsof /usr/share/doc
```

Same for directly running the rm command

```
$ docker run --rm -it arm64v8/ubuntu:latest rm -rf /usr/share/doc
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/sed': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libpam-modules': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/util-linux': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mawk': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/gnupg': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/apt': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libreadline6': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/passwd': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mount': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/procps': Directory not empty
```

And with sudo

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -it arm64v8/ubuntu:latest rm -rf /usr/share/doc
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/sed': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libpam-modules': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/util-linux': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mawk': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/gnupg': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/apt': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/libreadline6': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/passwd': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/mount': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/doc/procps': Directory not empty
```

This is not listed as a known issue in [Docker Issues](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues). How do I debug the issue further?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't in use? Check it woth `lsof`. Have you tried with `rmdir`?

Comment: I checked with `lsof` and also tried with `rmdir`. The directory isn't in use. I updated the question to include these additional debug steps.

Comment: I was trying to build a container with your Dockerfile but I'm getting an `exec format` error just when running the `rm -rf` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reporting it as an issue at [Docker overlay storage driver unable to delete directories from underlying image layer #35257](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35257), I got to the bottom of it, thanks to thaJeztah.

As documented at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/, the overlay storage driver requires kernel version 3.18 or newer.

My system uses the image [ArchLinuxARM-odroid-c2-latest.tar.gz](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/amlogic/odroid-c2) which has an older kernel version 3.14.

The problem occurs because the ALARM docker package is configured with the overlay driver by default, which will only work on newer kernel versions (e.g. RPi image or mainline kernel for ODROID-C2).

Therefore, the solution is to either

- Upgrade the kernel version. The last time I checked, mainline kernel support for ODROID-C2 had issues, so the next option might be preferable.
- Or configure docker to use the AUFS storage driver instead of the overlay driver.